# sfdx force:source:deploy is failing with ECONNRESET error

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, cicd, pipelines

One of my sandboxes I use for my CI pipeline has begun to fail on deployments. However, the Deployment Status tab in Salesforce shows the deployment as succeeding, most of the time.

Running the command:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x deployFolder/package/package.xml --verbose  -l RunSpecifiedTests -r {list of tests for the changed metadata} --loglevel TRACE --wait 60
```

produces the following error:

```
*** Deploying with SOAP API v54.0 ***
Deploy ID: 0Af9r000000YHpkCAG
DEPLOY PROGRESS | █████████████████████████████████████░░░ | 285/309 ComponentsError: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:691:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:402:19)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at node:net:687:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:580:7) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}

ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Metadata API request failed: aborted
```

The strange thing is that it is currently only on this sandbox at the moment. It also seems to have begun at the same time at Salesforce had connection issues with it's Hyperforce instances this morning (March 23).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this issue? Or where to look to pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even i have faced the same. Check the link in the comment https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/372233/getting-errors-from-yesterday-while-including-test-run-from-sfdx-command?noredirect=1#comment540155_372233