# Getting errors from yesterday while including test run from SFDX command

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

We have been receiving errors from our CI/CD process and from local python command whenever we deploy and tests are included in the package.

From Python command when I fire this:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --wait 180 -u orgname --resultformat json --codecoverage -d directoryName --testlevel RunLocalTests --verbose --json
```

I get :

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "name": "TypeError",
  "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Status')",
  "exitCode": 1,
  "commandName": "Run",
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Status')\n    at AsyncTests.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\apex-node\\lib\\src\\tests\\asyncTests.js:151:42)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\apex-node\\lib\\src\\tests\\asyncTests.js:11:58)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\nOuter stack:\n    at Function.wrap (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:171:27)\n    at Run.catch (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-apex\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:248:67)\n    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async Run._run (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\plugin-apex\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\command\\lib\\sfdxCommand.js:85:13)\n    at async Config.runCommand (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@oclif\\config\\lib\\config.js:173:24)\n    at async SfdxMain.run (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\main.js:27:9)\n    at async SfdxMain._run (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\node_modules\\@oclif\\command\\lib\\command.js:43:20)\n    at async Object.run (C:\\Users\\nagen\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.142.1-05bbd4a\\dist\\cli.js:162:47)",
  "warnings": [
    "WARNING: In the Summer ’21 release, we'll rename or remove some of the output files that are created when you run force:apex:test:run or force:apex:test:report with the --outputdir (-d) parameter.  This breaking change could impact your CI/CD scripts if they reference specific filenames. See https://sfdc.co/apex-test-updates for details\n"
  ]
}
```

Even from CI/CD when I run :

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -x deltaPackageGoesHere --checkonly -l 'RunSpecifiedTests' -r $TestClasses -u ProdUserName -w 60 --dev-debug
```

---

```
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████░░░░░ | 43/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████░░░░░ | 43/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████░░░░░ | 43/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ███████████████████████████████████░░░░░ | 43/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | █████████████████████████████████████░░░ | 45/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | █████████████████████████████████████░░░ | 45/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | █████████████████████████████████████░░░ | 45/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of null
    at /usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/node_modules/jsforce/lib/api/metadata.js:53:16
    at tryCallOne (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
From previous event:
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
From previous event:
    at Force.mdapiCheckDeployStatus (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/core/force.js:610:53)
    at CheckStatus._getStatus (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/mdapi/mdapiCheckStatusApi.js:89:21)
    at CheckStatus._pollForStatus (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/lib/mdapi/mdapiCheckStatusApi.js:56:14)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
SOURCE PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 47/49 Components
```

Comment: Hi Nagendra, This seems to be known issue from salesforce. Can you check the below url for the same and workaround as well . https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002JjgrQAC

Comment: The workaround mentioned there didnt work for me, though the error is exactly same.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves When deploying in production we need to run specific test class or all test class, in that way it becomes a blocker.

Comment: To clarify, the actual validation that happens in production can be successful, right? It's an error in the command solely? I got my previous comment wrong (deleted) - You can use `-w 0` to run the deployment async to avoid the command error when it tries to read the test results. You'll get the deployment Id back and then have to implement logic on your end to check the results. It's certainly not ideal, but thought that might be better than the workaround on the KI (especially if it doesn't work for you)

Comment: We do deployment via github actions. So we need to wait for the deployment and test results to be available before we move on to another job. Async wont work here for us.

Comment: I have no way to confirm it, but you can try to use the `force:source;deploy:report` command with wait specified (`-w`). I can't confirm because I can't test it (nor do I run into this issue), but I believe the issue is with `apex:test:run` specifically. So it's essentially the same as what you had before except you're switching which command waits for the results.